# How to change button value?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, boonex-dolphin

```
<input onclick="getInvitevalue(__id__, this)" type="button" value="Invite" name="InviteTeacher" class="InviteTeacher" id= "InviteTeacher"/>

<input onclick="getCancelvalue(__id__, InviteTeacher)" type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" class="Cancel" id= "Cancel"/>function getInvitevalue(idValue,invite){var field1 = idValue;
$.ajax({  url: "inviteteacher.php",  type: "POST",  data: ({name: field1}),}).done(function() {
if(invite.value = 'Invite')
invite.value = 'Pending Request';});}function getCancelvalue(idValue,cancel){var field2 = idValue;
$.ajax({  url: "inviteteacher.php",  type: "POST",  data: ({name: field2}),}).done(function() { 
if(cancel.value = 'Pending Request')
cancel.value = 'Invite';});}
```

Here onclick id which is used to display dynamic values.Refer my code and say how I change it in boonex-Dolphin??

Comment: Sure, what you try so far?.. can you post your code to a fiddle to play with?

Comment: Which type of button? HTML markup for the button please?

Comment: So you tried nothing ??

Comment: Try this

    <input type="button" class="invite" value="Invite" />
    <input type="button" class="cancel" value="Cancel" />
    
    $(".invite").click(function(){
       $(".invite").val("Pending Request");
    });
    
    $(".cancel").click(function(){
      $(".invite").val("Invite");
    });

Comment: @EswaraReddy That is not a comment, please don't answer questions with a comment.

Comment: @Conner ok i won't do next time.

Comment: @EswaraReddy cool, if you would have put that code in a answer, you could have got some points.

Comment: I am not able to answer this question. Here the answer text area is not displaying.

Comment: @conner Yes.Where can I add the code if I want add more?

Comment: @ManiamuthaKrish Late reply, but you would click the `edit` button under your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorter code--> no need of wrapping butoons in div

[new shorter DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ECyKR/2/)

```
$('.b2').attr('disabled', true);
$('.b1').click(function () {
    this.value = 'Pending Request';
    $(this).next('.b2').removeAttr('disabled');
});
$('.b2').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true).prev('.b1').val('Invite');
});
```

Now using class for the button and buttons are wrapped in div

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ECyKR/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="button" class="b1" value="Invite" />
    <input type="button" class="b2" value="Cancel" />
</div>

$('.b2').attr('disabled', true);
$('.b1').click(function () {
    this.value = 'Pending Request';
    $(this).parents('div').find('.b2').removeAttr('disabled');
});
$('.b2').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true).parents('div').find('.b1').val('Invite');
});
```

`$('#b1')` refers to the `element` with id `b1`

`this.value = 'Pending Request'` change the text of the current element clicked in below code change value of `element` with id `b1`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ECyKR/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="b1" value="Invite" />
<input type="button" id="b2" value="Cancel" />
```

**js**

```
$('#b1').click(function () {
    this.value = 'Pending Request';
});
$('#b2').click(function () {
    $('#b1').val('Invite');
});
```

Comment: Its work fine only for first member. What about next next??

Comment: Waiting for your reply..

Comment: @ManiamuthaKrish what do you mean working for first member only ??

Comment: I have listed the members. The Invite,cancel buttons are display in each member like Facebook.

Comment: See my codings.The id are fetch from Database.The Invite button is working fine for all members because of using 'this'. But the cancel button not working for all members.

Comment: @ManiamuthaKrish check updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ECyKR/1/

Comment: Thanks.I expect this one..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26V2t/)**, I have also set the cancel button to disabled when no request is running and so on.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="btn_start_request">Invite</button>
<button id="btn_cancel_request">Cancel</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function startRequest() {
    $("#btn_start_request").text("Pending request ..").attr("disabled", true)
    $("#btn_cancel_request").attr("disabled", false)

    // start request here
}
function cancelRequest() {
    $("#btn_start_request").text("Invite").attr("disabled", false)
    $("#btn_cancel_request").bind("click", cancelRequest).attr("disabled", true)

    // cancel request here
}

$(function() {
    $("#btn_start_request").bind("click", startRequest)
    $("#btn_cancel_request").bind("click", cancelRequest).attr("disabled", true)
})
```